# Start iOS Twilio service on device boot

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, voip

I have integrated twilio sdk in my app. It is working well after that my app is started. If the app is in background or foreground the incoming is notified. Nothing to complain.

BUT

If the user has restart his phone and did not launch my app, the Twilio service is not listening to incoming calls and then my user is not reachable.

So my question is : how to make my app listen to Twilio incoming call at device start up ?

EDIT: I obviously have the same problem if the user quit the app (from the menu). The app is not in background anymore and then the device is not reachable...